# Flutter FutureBuilder return null

Tags: flutter

when listing the data in my local database with FutureBuilder snapshot return null. I don't listing my data. when I check connection status it is waiting. when debugprint dbHelper.randevuListesiGetir() method, my data listening console screnn but not listening futurebuilder.

[image]

```
class _RandevularState extends State<Randevular> {
  DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
  List<Randevu> tumRandevular;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

      dbHelper=DatabaseHelper();
     tumRandevular=List<Randevu>();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future:dbHelper.randevuListesiGetir() ,
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<Randevu>> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
          tumRandevular=snapshot.data;
          print("data"+snapshot.data.toString());
        }else if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
          print("waiting");
        }else{
          print("error");
        }

      },
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: try putting in  return after the if statement

Answer (score 1):

these metods in databasehelper class

```
  Future<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> randevuGetir() async {
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var sonuc = await db.query("randevu");
    print("sonuc:$sonuc");
    return sonuc;
  }

  Future<List<Randevu>> randevuListesiGetir() async {
    var randevuMapListesi = await randevuGetir();
    var randevuListesi = List<Randevu>();
    for(Map map in randevuMapListesi){
      randevuListesi.add(Randevu.fromMap(map));
    }
    print(randevuListesi);
    return randevuListesi;

  }
```

these cods my randevular page

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kuaforapp/models/musteri.dart';
import 'package:kuaforapp/models/randevu.dart';
import 'package:kuaforapp/utils/database_helper.dart';

class Randevular extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandevularState createState() => _RandevularState();
}

class _RandevularState extends State<Randevular> {
  List<Randevu> tumRAndevular;
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    tumRAndevular = List<Randevu>();
    databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: databaseHelper.randevuListesiGetir(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Randevu>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          tumRAndevular = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: tumRAndevular.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(tumRAndevular[index].randevuId.toString()),
                );
              });
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you need to check if your snapshot has data before trying to do anything with snapshot.data. I have couple tips in the end.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _RandevularState extends State<Randevular> {
  DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
  List<Randevu> tumRandevular;
  Future<List<Randevu>> randevuFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();
    randevuFuture = dbHelper.randevuListesiGetir();
    tumRandevular = List<Randevu>();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: randevuFuture,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Randevu>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print("Data: ${snapshot.data}");
          final randevuList = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: randevuList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final currentRandevu = randevuList[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("${currentRandevu.name}"),
                );
              });
        }
        // Also check for possible errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print("An error occurred");
          return Text("An error occurred");
        }
        // You probably want to show loading indicator before you have data
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

- It's a builder method, you have to return widget from that.
- Make your API calls in the `initState`, not in the future: part. Since you give function call in the `future:`, `FutureBuilder` will call that in every build.

Comment: What’s the problem? Same error, new error? Please be more descriptive. If your snapshot has error(snapshot.hasError), probably your function call(randevuListesiniGetir) fails. You need to check that.

Comment: my functions is there Future<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> randevuGetir()async{ var db=await _getDatabase(); var sonuc=await db.query("randevu"); print("sonuc:$sonuc"); return sonuc; } Future<List<Randevu>> randevuListesiGetir()async{ var randevuMapListesi=await randevuGetir(); var randevuListesi=List<Randevu>(); for(Map map in randevuMapListesi){ randevuListesi.add(Randevu.fromMap(map)); } print(randevuListesi); return randevuListesi; }

Comment: @Mustafa we can't understand if your function works or not, it's dependent to the database. You need to debug it and make sure it's not returning null. Adding code to the original post is also better, hard to read unformatted code in the comments.

Comment: I share classes and widgets page with answer

Comment: You need to ask this question separately if it's related to your Database methods. Can you check if you can retrieve data from db before start to show them in the UI?

Comment: When I print my data with degubprint, I can see it on the Consol screen. I shared the screenshot above.